# Union mysql tables with just one common column

Tags: mysql, union

Please help me to find a solution for my case. I have n tables with follow structure

| main_id | sec_id | col_name_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | aaa |
| 2 | 8 | bbb |

| main_id | sec_id | col_name_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | ccc |
| 2 | 8 | bbb |

...

| main_id | sec_id | col_name_n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | ddd |
| 3 | 7 | eee |

What I want to have is:

| main_id | sec_id | col_name1 | col_name_2 | ... | col_name_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | aaa | ccc |  | ddd |
| 2 | 8 | bbb | bbb |  | null |
| 3 | 7 | null | null |  | eee |

Is it possible to union such tables?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a `union`, it's a `join`.

```
Select table1.main_id, table1.sec_id, col_name1, col_name2, ..., col_name_n
From table1
Cross Join table2 on table1.main_id = table2.main_id
Cross Join table3 on table1.main_id = table3.main_id
...
Cross Join tableN on table1.main_id = tableN.main_id
Where ...
```

The problem you are going to run into is getting the "main_id" and "sec_id" for "table3" if they don't exist in "table1". You can use a null coalesce, but that gets really ugly when looking at as many tables you describe.

```
Select COALESCE(table1.main_id, table2.main_id, table3.main_id, ..., tableN.main_id), 
  COALESCE(table1.sec_id, table2.sec_id, table3.sec_id, ..., tableN.sec_id),
...
```

Learn more about [join](https://www.guru99.com/joins.html)s and [union](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unions-clause.htm)s to figure out what's appropriate for you needs.

A `join` is when you want to intermix your columns and when they have one or multiple common column(s) that you can match rows to each other, like you are trying to do.

A `union` is where you are doing different queries on different (or the same) tables, but you want a single list, which also tends to mean that the columns are the same or renamed to be the same.

Comment: I forget to say, that it is in mysql. I need so full outer join. Is it maybe union?

Comment: I tried to join so how you suggested, but it seems like cross-table.

Comment: @Margot, a better link for MySQL joins would be https://www.guru99.com/joins.html. I'll update the answer, but it does seem as if a "cross join" might be what you are looking for. The thing to watch for is that with multiple tables, this can get to be a very large result set very quickly. And it's still not a union. Unions don't allow you to mix columns together like you want, and you would get rows with duplicate main_id, and sec_id.